# how fix USB device descriptor read/64, error

Tags: 18.04, usb, kde

```
[  226.497985] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[  226.577995] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  226.765942] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  226.953903] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[  227.034054] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  227.221941] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  227.330127] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[  227.933911] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[  228.349875] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 10, error -32
[  228.429848] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[  228.845808] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 11, error -32
[  228.845975] usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[  252.452583] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  252.532639] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  252.720656] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  252.908588] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[  252.988631] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  253.180596] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  253.288810] usb 1-1-port1: attempt power cycle
[  253.892488] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[  254.308536] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 14, error -32
[  254.392472] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[  254.808458] usb 1-1.1: device not accepting address 15, error -32
[  254.808681] usb 1-1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Comment: I had a cheap external hub that produced loads of those type errors, it did it on any computer on which the hub was connected, so I just replaced the hub (on windows those went to event.viewer where it's seldom noticed except by scammers trying to sell you *unneeded protection*)   Note: this may not be your issue, but I'd see if disconnecting a 'cheap' hub causes them to disappear :)

Comment: Same here with a cheap dongle (says "V5.0" on it) from China. Also `lsusb` does not show anything.